# Disable button if edit text field is empty. Can't get it to working

Tags: android

Currently I am learning to code and came across one problem. I need my upload button to be disabled untill Edit Text field is somekind of symbol than default hint
[Full code](https://pastebin.com/Q7c3832c)

```
    private TextWatcher EmptyEdit = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            mUpload.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            mUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Hope you are setting the watcher on mUpload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your code in afterTextChanged() instead of onTextChanged().

```
 private TextWatcher EmptyEdit = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    mUpload.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    mUpload.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Do your code inside `afterTextChanged()`.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    mUpload.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()))
}

// don't forget to set listner
editText.addTextChangedListener(EmptyEdit);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

     //Disable your button in here

    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tryed that. Probably I am putting my function at the wrong place

Comment: No but as I said most likely I am writting at wrong place

Comment: Yep, I wrote it at wrong place. Thank you for your time